# how can i get sum of last 3 transaction in sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have a table name attendents and i want to get sum of last 3 transaction of each mem_id
i write query to get sum of all transaction for each mem_id.but i didnt know how to get sum of last 3 transaction for each member.

i am using ms accsess database thank you
my table data is

```
CREATE TABLE `attendents` (
    `tr_id` INTEGER,
    `mem_id`    NUMERIC,
    `result`    INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`tr_id`)
);
```

my current query is

```
select mem_id,sum(result)
from attendents
group by mem_id
;
```

my table data is
tr_id | mem_id | result 
1            1          1  
2          2         0  
3          1         0  
4          2         1  
5          1         1  
6          2         1  
7          1         0  
8          2         1

then last 3 transaction sum should be  mem_id 1= 1  and mem_id 2=3

Comment: Which database are you really using?

Comment: You've listed a ton of different databases.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: @gurv Numeric is a clue

Comment: hello,i am using ms accsess database thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which DBMS you are really using.

If you are using **`MS Access`**, use `TOP`:

```
select a.mem_id,
    Sum(a.result) as SumOfresult
from attendents as a
where a.tr_id in (
        select top 3 tr_id
        from attendents a2
        where a.mem_id = a2.mem_id
        order by tr_id desc
        )
group by a.mem_id;
```

If you are using **`MySQL`**, you can use user variables to generate partitioned sequence numbers to use in where clause later to limit the transactions to latest three.

```
select
    mem_id,
    sum(result)
from (
    select
        t.*,
        @rn := if(
                @mem_id = mem_id, 
                @rn + 1,
                if(@mem_id := mem_id, 1, 1)
                ) rn
    from (
        select *
        from attendents
        order by mem_id, tr_id desc
    ) t cross join (select @mem_id := -1, @rn := 0) t2
) t where rn <= 3
group by mem_id;
```

If you are using **`SQL server`**, it's easier to do. You can use window function row_number to generate the sequence numbers:

```
select mem_id, sum(result)
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over (
            partition by mem_id order by tr_id desc
            ) seqnum
    from attendents a
    ) t
where seqnum <= 3
group by mem_id;
```

In **`SQLite`**, you can use a correlated subquery to limit the row to latest three transaction per mem_id (assuming tr_id is unique):

```
select mem_id, sum(result)
from attendents a
where tr_id in (
        select tr_id
        from attendents a2
        where a.mem_id = a2.mem_id
        order by tr_id desc limit 3
        )
group by mem_id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer  
 
hello,i am using ms accsess database thank you

Comment: @ashan - Updated the answer. See the first query.

Comment: @ashan - I see you accepted the answer then unaccepted it. You are the OP and it's completely your right to decide whether to accept it or not, but is there a reason please? Does it not do what you want?

Comment: hello.thanks again but its not work .the result is not i want get .my table data result include only 1 and 0 .if i run correct this query value result sum should be 3 or below 3.thank you

Comment: @ashan - Please **[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42593243/edit)** your question and add sample data from your table and the result your expect.

Comment: @ashan - also, is the tr_id unique? (it should be). I've tested this query with some data and it produced correct result.

Comment: hello,your sql lite query is working

Comment: thanks again its working sorry for my mistake can you explain me how its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
select mem_id,sum(result)
from (select top(3) mem_id, result from attendents order by tr_id desc)
group by mem_id
;
```

Comment: The OP is not using SQL Server.

Comment: hello,i am using ms accsess database thank you

Comment: hello thanks for answering .but its not work.there is error masesge show "the select statement include reserve word or argument that is missing"